# canvas on top of a grid tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, grid

I want to put a canvas on top of a larger sized grid so that I can create buttons at the bottom of the canvas. Right now I have this:

```
class Canvas(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.display = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, borderwidth=5, background='white')
        self.display.pack()

root = Tk()
board = Canvas(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This creates a 500x500 white canvas. Now let's say I want to add something like a 500x600 grid to go under it. How would I do that?

Comment: Are you saying you want to _draw_ a grid -- a series of horizontal and vertical lines? What do you mean by "put a canvas on a larger grid"? In tkinter, a "grid" isn't a thing. `grid` is simply a method that arranges objects in a grid, but it doesn't actually create anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pack another frame under it, with `height=100` and `pack` it with `fill=X`. Then you can put the `Buttons` in this new frame any way you want.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

display = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, borderwidth=5, background='white')
display.pack()

button_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=100)
button_frame.pack(fill=tk.X)
button1 = tk.Button(button_frame, text='button1')
button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
button2 = tk.Button(button_frame, text='button2')
button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Or, if you really want a `grid`, you can use the following code to place the `Frame` under the `Canvas`

```
display = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500, borderwidth=5, background='white')
display.grid(column=0, row=0)

button_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=100)
button_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)
```

But if you place the `Canvas` with `pack`, don't try to put the frame in with `grid`. Use only one layout manager in `root`.